# Printing a range of numbers - including end value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following dictionary:

```
self.info("check_reg_min_max")
self.info(pprint.pformat(check_reg_min_max))


{
'TXH1DH50_DD70_03062018_FULL': [60398572, 60399376],
'TXH2DH50_DD70_03062018_FULL': [5071407, 5071709],
'TXH3DH50_DD70_03062018_FULL': [2822010, 2822116],
'TXH4DH50_DD70_03062018_FULL': [52148625, 52148782],
'TXH5DH50_DD70_03062018_FULL': [6764732, 6764766]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is write each range of numbers to a file, so I'm doing this:

```
for filename in check_reg_min_max:
        jc.write(range(check_reg_min_max[filename][0], check_reg_min_max[filename][1] + 1))
```

The error message I keep getting is:

```
argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not list
```

My understanding is that `range` takes two integers, and since it is inclusive, I am adding the `+1` to grab the end value.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I grabbed the wrong error message. Error message updated.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback? I don't see your code calling `split` anywhere

Comment: Also, a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice

Comment: The error message states that you are passing a list to the (presumably) `range` - not the int you think you are passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The write() method expects a string. You can't pass it a range directly, it doesn't know what to do with that. This won't work:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write(range(1,10))
f.close()
```

You'd need to do something to convert that range to a string. This is one example of how you might do that, if you wanted a comma-separated list of values:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write(','.join([str(x) for x in range(1,10)]))
f.close()
```